# HX711 : Inductor on supply line and feedback

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, inductor

I'm re-implementing the great HX711 breakout board from Sparkfun (schematics : https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/f/5/5/b/c/SparkFun_HX711_Load_Cell.pdf).

I'm trying to understand the exact role of the inductor (I think it removes high frequency noises but an explanation would be great).

The real issue I have with this circuit is:

Why is the feedback of the regulator measured **before** the inductor and not **after**?
[image]

Comment: Is there a data sheet for the bare bones chip?

Comment: Yes : https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/ForceFlex/hx711_english.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is the feedback of the regulator measured before the inductor and not after?

Connecting the feedback left or right of the inductor will hardly have effect on the voltage *regulation*.

Probably the designer first designed the feedback control for the internal analog supply regulator and next decided to add an additional LC filter to reduce noise to the supply to the load cell even more.
(The LC filter is to filter the noise coming from the supply that is connected to VSUP (pin 1) of the HX711.)

What surprises me more is that pin 3 of the HX711 is still connected *before* the LC filter. It might be due to my assumption the LC filter has been added later.

Comment: I think I understand the component a bit better. The pin 3 AVDD is the supply for the amplification circuit, thus needs to be clean from any noise coming from the environment of the load cell. The noise from the power supply is already filtered (not shown in the screenshot) by two capas and the BJT.

Comment: @Salamandar No, I think it is to filter noise from the power supply as I wrote. Maybe it is superfluous because there are already 2 caps, as you write. But if it were to filter noise ***entering* the E+ label** on your schematic, the L should preceed the C to form a LC filter, so the L should be on the **left** side of C8 and C9.

Answer (score 0):

Before and after is relative.  Which direction would the noise come from?
It would come from the load cell side which is on the left of L1.

BTW, the noise isn't from the load cell itself, it's from the enviornment and long wires that are between the load cell and L1.

Comment: If the noise would come *from the enviornment and long wires that are between the load cell and L1*, why using a CL filter instead of a LC filter?

Comment: Moreover, noise that couples in the supply leads to the load cell, will  disturb INA+ and INA- anyway. The CL filter won't help anymore.

Comment: I guess the noise in INA+/INA- would be filtered by the differential measure.

Comment: @Aaron that's an interesting way of seeing things. I'll think about that.

Comment: @Salamandar When noise couples into the positive supply lead towards the load cell, it is differential noise which will disturb the measurement. The differential measure of  INA+/INA- will **not** cancel that, because differential measurements cannot cancel differential noise.

Comment: @Salamandar When the noise is common mode, C8, C9 and L1 will hardly do anything.